# Named Pipes with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I’ve established communication between two separate processes on the same computer using System.IO.Pipes (console app and GUI app).
The console app NamedPipeServerStream creates a pipe while the GUI app NamedPipeClientStream connects to an existing pipe. I have very frequent updates of the GUI. 
My question is, is the Named Pipes technique most efficient way to handle this situation. The second question is would Reactive Extensions RX fit better for this situation and how?
Thank You in advance.

Server

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;

namespace PipeApplicationSender
{

    class ProgramPipeTest
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProgramPipeTest Server = new ProgramPipeTest();

            Thread ServerThread = new Thread( Server.ThreadStartServer );

            ServerThread.Start();
        }


        public void ThreadStartServer()
        {
            // Create a name pipe
            using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("mytestpipe"))
            {

                // Wait for a connection
                pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("[Server] Pipe connection established");

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
                {
                    string temp;
                    // We read a line from the pipe and print it together with the current time
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Client

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;

namespace PipeApplicationReceiver
{

    class ProgramPipeReceive
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProgramPipeReceive Server = new ProgramPipeReceive ();

            Thread ServerThread = new Thread( Server.ThreadStartServer );

            ServerThread.Start();
        }


        public void ThreadStartClient(object obj)
        {
            // Ensure that we only start the client after the server has created the pipe
            ManualResetEvent SyncClientServer = (ManualResetEvent)obj;

            // Only continue after the server was created -- otherwise we just fail badly
            // SyncClientServer.WaitOne();

            using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("mytestpipe"))
            {
                // The connect function will indefinately wait for the pipe to become available
                // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
                pipeStream.Connect();

                Console.WriteLine("[Client] Pipe connection established");
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream))
                {
                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    string temp;
                  while ((temp = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (temp == "quit") break;
                        sw.WriteLine(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Named pipes are the conduit, RX could be a good choice in how your client and server process the messages you send over the conduit.

Comment: So, basicly you say that I should keep the transaction As it Is and modify the handling of data prior and after sending, since we can pass only the raw strings?

Comment: Not sure what you question is really. I don't see your transactions in your examples, do you mean messages? And named pipes are a low level construct that can send more than strings for messages if you wish. Not that there's anything wrong with strings.

Comment: Yes, I meant messages sorry... can I send also an collection so I can easily convert it to an observable ? So, would it benefit at all if I use an RX ?

Comment: I think you should read up on framing low-level communication over named pipes and how you might serialized whatever it is you want to send and then post a new specific question on any issue(s) you have. You're on the right track. RX is a design choice, there are many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: I found good example messaging the collection http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a514ff1d-91c2-4443-8469-117d7707a82d/passiing-class-object-via-named-pipes-in-c

Answer (score 3):

https://gist.github.com/hanishi/7139122

I just made a complete IpcServer and IpcClient with Rx. I hope you like it.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I myself need to write one, so here is what I have. This one will not block the calling thread.

Usage:

```
        PipeStreamObservable.Create(out stream, "testpipe")
                              .Subscribe(str =>
                                  {

                                      Console.WriteLine(str);

                                  },
                                  Console.WriteLine,
                                  Console.WriteLine);

OR

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        NamedPipeServerStream stream;

        PipeStreamObservable.Create<Hashtable>(out stream, "testpipe", formatter)
                              .Subscribe(table =>
                                  {

                                      Console.WriteLine(table["abc"]);

                                  },
                                  Console.WriteLine,
                                  Console.WriteLine);


Code:

public static class PipeStreamObservable
{
    private static readonly PipeSecurity PipeSecurity;
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("weldR");
    static PipeStreamObservable()
    {
        PipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
        PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(
            new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow)
        );
        PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(
            new PipeAccessRule(
                new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow
            )
        );
    }

    public static void Write<T>(this NamedPipeClientStream stream, T type, IFormatter formatter) where T : ISerializable
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, type);
    }

    public static void Write<T>(this NamedPipeServerStream stream, T type, IFormatter formatter) where T : ISerializable
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, type);
    }

    public static int Write(this NamedPipeClientStream stream, string str)
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        var len = buffer.Length;
        if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
        {
            len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
        }
        stream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
        stream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        stream.Flush();
        return buffer.Length + 2;
    }

    public static int Write(this NamedPipeServerStream stream, string str)
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        var len = buffer.Length;
        if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
        {
            len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
        }
        stream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
        stream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        stream.Flush();
        return buffer.Length + 2;
    }

    public static IObservable<T> Create<T>(out NamedPipeServerStream stream, string pipeName, IFormatter formatter)
    {
        stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut,
            1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        var serverStream = stream;
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            var currentStateSubscription = new SerialDisposable();

            return NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(
                new FormatterIterator<T>(serverStream, formatter), (state, self) =>
                    currentStateSubscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(str =>
                        {
                            self(state);
                            o.OnNext(str);
                        },
                        o.OnError,
                        () =>
                        {
                            currentStateSubscription.Dispose();
                            o.OnCompleted();
                        })
                );
        });
    }

    public static IObservable<string> Create(out NamedPipeServerStream stream, string pipeName)
    {
        stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut,
            1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        var serverStream = stream;
        return Observable.Create<string>(o =>
        {

            var currentStateSubscription = new SerialDisposable();

            return NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(
                new StringIterator(serverStream), (state, self) =>
                    currentStateSubscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(str =>
                        {
                            self(state);
                            o.OnNext(str);
                        },
                        o.OnError,
                        () =>
                            {
                                currentStateSubscription.Dispose();
                                o.OnCompleted();
                            })
                );
        });
    }

    public static IObservable<string> Create(out NamedPipeClientStream stream, string server, string pipeName)
    {
        stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(server, pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        var serverStream = stream;
        return Observable.Create<string>(o =>
        {

            var currentStateSubscription = new SerialDisposable();

            return NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(
                new StringIterator(serverStream), (state, self) =>
                    currentStateSubscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(str =>
                        {
                            self(state);
                            o.OnNext(str);
                        },
                        o.OnError,
                        () =>
                        {
                            currentStateSubscription.Dispose();
                            o.OnCompleted();
                        })
                );
        });
    }

    public static IObservable<T> Create<T>(out NamedPipeClientStream stream, 
        string server, 
        string pipeName, 
        IFormatter formatter)
    {
        stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(server, pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        var serverStream = stream;
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {

            var currentStateSubscription = new SerialDisposable();

            return NewThreadScheduler.Default.Schedule(
                new FormatterIterator<T>(serverStream, formatter), (state, self) =>
                    currentStateSubscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(str =>
                            {
                                self(state);
                                o.OnNext(str);
                            },
                            o.OnError,
                            () =>
                                {
                                    currentStateSubscription.Dispose();
                                    o.OnCompleted();
                                })
                );
        });
    }

    private delegate bool StreamHandler<T>(Stream input, out T output);

    public interface IIterator<out T>
    {
        IObservable<T> ReadNext();
    }

    private abstract class ReaderState<T> : IIterator<T>
    {
        public abstract IObservable<T> ReadNext();
    }

    private class ReadReadyState<T> : ReaderState<T>
    {
        private readonly Stream _stream;
        private readonly StreamHandler<T> _handler;

        internal ReadReadyState(Stream stream, StreamHandler<T> handler)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public override IObservable<T> ReadNext()
        {
            return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    T value;
                    if (_handler(_stream, out value))
                        o.OnNext(value);
                }
                catch (SerializationException e)
                {
                    Logger.Debug(e);
                    o.OnCompleted();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Debug(e);
                    o.OnError(e);
                    return _stream;
                }
                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }
    }

    private class ServerStreamReader<T> : IIterator<T>
    {
        private ReaderState<T> _currentState;
        private readonly NamedPipeServerStream _stream;
        private readonly StreamHandler<T> _handler; 

        internal ServerStreamReader(NamedPipeServerStream stream, StreamHandler<T> handler)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _handler = handler;
            _currentState = new ConnectionWaitState<T>(this);
        }

        private class ConnectionWaitState<T1> : ReaderState<T1>
        {
            private readonly ServerStreamReader<T1> _parent;

            internal ConnectionWaitState(ServerStreamReader<T1> parent)
            {
                _parent = parent;
            }

            public override IObservable<T1> ReadNext()
            {
                try
                {
                    _parent._stream.WaitForConnection();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }
                _parent._currentState = new ReadReadyState<T1>(_parent._stream, _parent._handler);
                return _parent._currentState.ReadNext();
            }
        }

        public IObservable<T> ReadNext()
        {
            return _currentState.ReadNext();
        }
    }

    private class ClientStreamReader<T> : IIterator<T>
    {
        private ReaderState<T> _currentState;
        private readonly NamedPipeClientStream _stream;
        private readonly StreamHandler<T> _handler;

        internal ClientStreamReader(NamedPipeClientStream stream, StreamHandler<T> handler)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _handler = handler;
            _currentState = new ConnectionWaitState<T>(this);
        }

        private class ConnectionWaitState<T1> : ReaderState<T1>
        {
            private readonly ClientStreamReader<T1> _parent;

            internal ConnectionWaitState(ClientStreamReader<T1> parent)
            {
                _parent = parent;
            }

            public override IObservable<T1> ReadNext()
            {
                try
                {
                    _parent._stream.Connect();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }
                _parent._currentState = new ReadReadyState<T1>(_parent._stream, _parent._handler);
                return _parent._currentState.ReadNext();
            }
        }

        public IObservable<T> ReadNext()
        {
            return _currentState.ReadNext();
        }
    }

    private sealed class FormatterIterator<T> : IIterator<T>
    {
        private readonly IIterator<T> _iterator;
        private readonly IFormatter _formatter;

        public FormatterIterator(NamedPipeServerStream source, IFormatter formatter)
        {
            _iterator = new ServerStreamReader<T>(source, DeserializeWithFormatter);
            _formatter = formatter;
        }

        public FormatterIterator(NamedPipeClientStream source, IFormatter formatter)
        {
            _iterator = new ClientStreamReader<T>(source, DeserializeWithFormatter);
            _formatter = formatter;
        }

        public IObservable<T> ReadNext()
        {
            return _iterator.ReadNext();
        }

        private bool DeserializeWithFormatter(Stream stream, out T value)
        {
            try
            {
                value = (T) _formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                return true;
            }
            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                value = default(T);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class StringIterator : IIterator<string>
    {
        private readonly IIterator<string> _iterator;

        private static bool DeserializeToString(Stream stream, out string value)
        {
            var len = stream.ReadByte();
            if (len < 0)
            {
                value = null;
                return false;
            }
            len *= 256;
            len += stream.ReadByte();
            var buffer = new byte[len];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, len);
            value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
            return true;
        }

        public StringIterator(NamedPipeServerStream source)
        {
            _iterator = new ServerStreamReader<string>(source, DeserializeToString);
        }

         public StringIterator(NamedPipeClientStream source)
        {
            _iterator = new ClientStreamReader<string>(source, DeserializeToString);
        }

        public IObservable<string> ReadNext()
        {
            return _iterator.ReadNext();
        }
    }
}
```